# Trying to prove the empty set is at most countable by the definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was wondering if the empty set is at most countable. Specifically, if it has to be defined in some sense like finite or countable or if it can be proved from the definition of countability what it is. 
Then I thought if I could be able to show that there is at least a surjective function between the natural numbers and the empty set. So I started thinking.

Let $\alpha$ be a function: $\alpha: \mathbb N \rightarrow \emptyset$.

Then we have that $\alpha(n) \notin Im(\alpha)$ for all $\ n \in \mathbb N$,
where $\alpha(n)$ is the value of the function $\alpha$ at $n$, i. e., $\alpha(1)$, $\alpha(2)$ ... , $\alpha(n),$ ...

In this manner, the image of $\alpha$ would be empty. But so it is the empty set, an there are no distinct empty sets. Therefore $\alpha$ is surjective (because the codomain equals the image of $\alpha$). As the empty set has no elements, it is at most countable, or better, it is finite.

What you guys think of this proof?

Thank you everybody, now I believe I know where I went wrong, in thinking that there are such functions!

Comment: What is your definition of "at most countable"?

Comment: Finite or countable.

Comment: Well then, what is your definition of finite?

Comment: There is no function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\emptyset$. In fact, there is no function $f:A\to\emptyset$ for any nonempty set $A$.

Comment: This is a good point. How to define finitude for the empty set. Sincerely, I do not know. The standart one would be put the set in one-to-one correspondence between the set {a : a between 0 and n - 1}, if there is such n then the former is said to be finite. But one can also think of the set that is countable but not infinite, therefore needing the previous definition.

Comment: Why there are no such functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument shows that if $\alpha:\mathbb{N}\to\emptyset$ is a function, then $\alpha$ is surjective.  However, this does not prove that there is a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\emptyset$: what if there are no such functions at all?  In fact, there aren't: what would $\alpha(1)$ be, for instance?

In any case, if your goal is to prove the empty set is at most countable "by the definition", then you need to use the definition.  The definition of "at most countable" is *not* that there exists a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ (though it is a theorem that if such a surjection exists, then your set is at most countable).  You said your definition is just that a set is at most countable if it is either countable or finite.  So you need to prove either that $\emptyset$ is countable or that it is finite.  It's not countable (assuming that by "countable" you mean countably infinite), so you'll have to prove that it's finite.

Again, if you want to prove this, you'll have to use the *definition* of "finite".  There are several different possible definitions, but the most common is that a set $S$ is finite if there is a bijection between $S$ and the set $\{m\in\mathbb{N}:m<n\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  In the case $S=\emptyset$, it is equal to the set $\{m\in\mathbb{N}:m<0\}$, so you can take $n=0$ and use the identity map as your bijection.

Comment: Well, have you tried writing one down?  I'll let you start simple: just tell me what you want to define $\alpha(1)$ to be.

Comment: The ideia was really use that theorem you have mentioned, I misused the term... I am sorry... I am trying to write $\alpha(1)$ as a contradictory assertion.

Comment: On the other hand the theorem is equivalent to the definition, so it can be used as a definition. I hope!

Comment: A thing like this: $\alpha(1)= \{1 : 1=2\} $. Something like that.

Comment: $\alpha(1)$ would be the empty set, so it is defined on the empty set. The same for the others $\alpha(n)$...  Am I going to far away?

Comment: But I agree with you. The inconsistency of my proof relies on the fact that there are no such functions. And I liked yours very much. Thank you!

Comment: The theorem is _not_ equivalent to the definition.  Defining $\alpha(1)=\emptyset$ does not work, because $\alpha(1)$ needs to be an _element_ of $\emptyset$.

Comment: So if I had the set of the empty set, the argument would work? @EricWofsey

Comment: Thank you very much, @Eric

Comment: If you had $\{\emptyset\}$, then you could define a function $\alpha:\mathbb{N}\to\{\emptyset\}$.  Your original argument that such a function is surjective would need some modification though.

Comment: Definition of countable by the book "Mathematical Logic" by -D.Ebbinghaus, Flum, and Thomas: "We call a set M countable if there is a surjective map of the set of natural numbers $\mathbb N = \{1, 2, 3 ...\}$ onto M. A set is called at most countable if it is countable or finite." Just for the question of the definition.

Comment: Well, that's a rather silly definition which is not standard.  By their definitions, a set is countable iff it is either countably infinite or finite and nonempty, and the only difference between "countable" and "at most countable" is that the empty set also counts as "at most countable".

Comment: Because of that it arose to me trying to define a function to the empty set, but now I know this is impossible. Because they define the empty set as finite, I tried to prove, instead of just accepting it as a definition.

Comment: But you has shown me the way.

Comment: I think they define in this way because they are talking about strings in a alphabet, and they have to distinguish the empty string. For it is a book about Mathematical Logic, and very much is not standard.